# What is the best way to upgrade logo of application and report in managed package?

Tags: visualforce, reporting, managed-package, force.com, package

E.g. client A have managed package v1.0 installed. Then you are releasing v1.1 with app logo changed. Currently, when you upgrade client A with v.1.1 logo won't be changed, since Document component is not "upgradable" according to this list https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm.

There is also idea related to that fact https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxalAAA.

The first idea was to include one more Document with another name into v1.1 and select it as Application logo, but Application is also not "upgradable".

The same situation with Reports (not "upgradable").

Is there any workaround, e.g. deleting not "upgradable" component (Document/Application/Report) in client's A org before upgrading to v1.1? They are all marked as "Subscriber Deletable".